# "wrong sample count" When reading MP4 files using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, mp4, video-processing

I want to marge some mp4 videos using OpenCV library, but when I try to read those videos using `cv::VideoCapture`, it outputs like that:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[h264 @ 000001EB9AAE9D80] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 000001EB9AAE7D80] co located POCs unavailable
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[h264 @ 000001EB9A128600] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 000001EB9A129840] co located POCs unavailable
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB9AA28E40] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[h264 @ 000001EB9A169B00] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 000001EB9A16B680] co located POCs unavailable
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[h264 @ 000001EB960CD680] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 000001EB960CC8C0] co located POCs unavailable
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[h264 @ 000001EB9A81DDC0] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 000001EB9A81B000] co located POCs unavailable
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[h264 @ 000001EB960CB200] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 000001EB960CBFC0] co located POCs unavailable
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[h264 @ 000001EB99F206C0] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 000001EB99F20B40] co located POCs unavailable
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[h264 @ 000001EB9A81D480] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 000001EB9A81B000] co located POCs unavailable
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[h264 @ 000001EB9AD02C00] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 000001EB9AD02300] co located POCs unavailable
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[h264 @ 000001EB9A81B480] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 000001EB9A81B940] co located POCs unavailable
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[h264 @ 000001EB9AD02780] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 000001EB9AD01E40] co located POCs unavailable
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001EB96084B80] wrong sample count
```

and just exited with exit value 0. I want to know why it is reporting this and how to solve it please.

Heres my demo code:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/video.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main()
{
        cv::Mat frame;
        cv::VideoCapture vcap;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 60; i++)
        {
            if (!vcap.open("G:\\Users\\15819\\Desktop\\Demo\\demo (" + std::to_string(i) + ").mp4"))
            {
                std::cout << "Failed to Open File: demo (" << i << ").mp4" << std::endl;
                continue;
            }
            while (!vcap.read(frame))
                cv::imshow("video", frame);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I installed the `OpenCV` and `FFmpeg` library using `vcpkg`, here's the library information (displayed by `vcpkg list` command):

```
ffmpeg:x64-windows                                4.4.1#21            a library to decode, encode, transcode, mux, dem...
ffmpeg:x86-windows                                4.4.1#21            a library to decode, encode, transcode, mux, dem...
ffmpeg[avcodec]:x64-windows                                           Build the avcodec library
ffmpeg[avcodec]:x86-windows                                           Build the avcodec library
ffmpeg[avdevice]:x64-windows                                          Build the avdevice library
ffmpeg[avdevice]:x86-windows                                          Build the avdevice library
ffmpeg[avfilter]:x64-windows                                          Build the avfilter library
ffmpeg[avfilter]:x86-windows                                          Build the avfilter library
ffmpeg[avformat]:x64-windows                                          Build the avformat library
ffmpeg[avformat]:x86-windows                                          Build the avformat library
ffmpeg[openh264]:x64-windows                                          H.264 de/encoding via openh264
ffmpeg[openh264]:x86-windows                                          H.264 de/encoding via openh264
ffmpeg[swresample]:x64-windows                                        Build the swresample library
ffmpeg[swresample]:x86-windows                                        Build the swresample library
ffmpeg[swscale]:x64-windows                                           Build the swscale library
ffmpeg[swscale]:x86-windows                                           Build the swscale library
opencv4:x64-windows                               4.6.0#6             computer vision library
opencv4:x86-windows                               4.6.0#6             computer vision library
opencv4[default-features]:x64-windows                                 Platform-dependent default features
opencv4[default-features]:x86-windows                                 Platform-dependent default features
opencv4[dnn]:x64-windows                                              Enable dnn module
opencv4[dnn]:x86-windows                                              Enable dnn module
opencv4[ffmpeg]:x64-windows                                           ffmpeg support for opencv
opencv4[ffmpeg]:x86-windows                                           ffmpeg support for opencv
opencv4[jpeg]:x64-windows                                             JPEG support for opencv
opencv4[jpeg]:x86-windows                                             JPEG support for opencv
opencv4[png]:x64-windows                                              PNG support for opencv
opencv4[png]:x86-windows                                              PNG support for opencv
opencv4[qt]:x64-windows                                               Qt GUI support for opencv
opencv4[qt]:x86-windows                                               Qt GUI support for opencv
opencv4[quirc]:x64-windows                                            Enable QR code module
opencv4[quirc]:x86-windows                                            Enable QR code module
opencv4[tiff]:x64-windows                                             TIFF support for opencv
opencv4[tiff]:x86-windows                                             TIFF support for opencv
opencv4[webp]:x64-windows                                             WebP support for opencv
opencv4[webp]:x86-windows                                             WebP support for opencv
opencv:x64-windows                                4.6.0               Computer vision library
opencv:x86-windows                                4.6.0               Computer vision library
opencv[default-features]:x64-windows                                  Platform-dependent default features
opencv[default-features]:x86-windows                                  Platform-dependent default features
opencv[dnn]:x64-windows                                               Enable dnn module
opencv[dnn]:x86-windows                                               Enable dnn module
opencv[jpeg]:x64-windows                                              JPEG support for opencv
opencv[jpeg]:x86-windows                                              JPEG support for opencv
opencv[png]:x64-windows                                               PNG support for opencv
opencv[png]:x86-windows                                               PNG support for opencv
opencv[quirc]:x64-windows                                             Enable QR code module
opencv[quirc]:x86-windows                                             Enable QR code module
opencv[tiff]:x64-windows                                              TIFF support for opencv
opencv[tiff]:x86-windows                                              TIFF support for opencv
opencv[webp]:x64-windows                                              WebP support for opencv
opencv[webp]:x86-windows                                              WebP support for opencv
```

Other Environments:

```
OS: Windows 11 x64 Professional Workstation
IDE: Visual Studio 2022
Project C++ Standard: C++14
Project Platform: x64 Release
```

Comment: are you able to read only one video at a time ?

Comment: Can you try to remove the exit on first failure? Even if vcap.read does not give you an image for let's say 100 calls there might be a full working image on the 101th call. I've seen a lot a images and streams where you have to skip "broken" frames by just reading the next ones. Typically I allow about 120 failures in a row before exiting.

Comment: Are you able to open the video file in vlc?

Comment: We can also ask: Is it working with other MP4 files? In case the code is working with other MP4 video files (encoded with H.264 codec), I recommend you to share the video file (if possible). Why are you opening 60 video files? Make sure the code is working with one video file first. Add `cv::waitKey(40)` after `cv::imshow`. Execute `vcap.release()` after finish reading a video file.

Comment: Thanks to @Micka , my problem has solved. If you want to make your comment a answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a473055e77dd7faa4d26d686226b292c1) ```read``` only returns false when "camera has been disconnected, or there are no more frames in video file". So your workaround should not work. This is a bug and worth reporting an [issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug&template=bug_report.yml)


Anyway, I think what is really going on is a broken file. Could you please post the result of ```ffprobe file.mp4```. And maybe you could upload a small file sample?